# How can I background a mailto in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, email

I want to create a form that works with ‘button id=“this” onclick=“sendToME”’ and I do not have my email reavealed (unless they open the console) at the moment of sending the data from the form.

Comment: If it's client-side the user will, or can (*very*, **very** ***easily***), see it. If you want it to be secure, submit the message content to the server and submit it to email (if you really feel that's the best way) server-side.

Comment: you're certainly not going to implement SMTP in the browser, so you'll need a service that accepts AJAX requests and generates email. Google "send email via ajax" and you'll find many results, from commercial services to setting up your own server.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to achieve your goal is to make an api endpoint (the button should point here), which are handle the process of email sending.